# setting a javascript / jquery function to a variable.. best practice? why?

Tags: jquery

I am updating some code that was created by another developer and am noticing that there are a lot of, what I can best describe as, functions inside functions and the whole object is set to a variable.

For example:

```
var spellcheck = {
checkone: function() {      
    <....>
    spellcheck.jspspellcheck.startSpellCheck( "/SpellChecker/", $(e.target).parent().prev('input:enabled, textarea:enabled') );

},  
jspspellcheck: {
    <....>
    startSpellCheck: function(baseUrl,elements){
        <....>          
        spellcheck.jspspellcheck.openCenteredWindow( );
    }
}
}
```

Obviously the above code is just a sample, but it does illistrate how a lot of the jQuery is written.

From the dot notation I it looks like it is making use of OO type practices, however having "functions" inside other functions gets quite confusing (at least to me).  Basically, should I try and refactor this code into different named functions or am I missing something that is a best practice?

Comment: Yes, it's confusing until you get used to seeing it. No, you shouldn't change it. Those functions are where they are for a reason. For instance, the "official" way of building jQuery plugins ( http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods ) recommends constructing an object of functions in just this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wouldn't really be "refactoring", it'd be "moving". Not that restructuring some of it wouldn't be good--there's just no way to tell from the posted code.

But why would you want to? They're in there to keep them out of the global namespace (one way of modularizing JS code).

Comment: The main reason why is the entire function call originates from an "onClick" that is attached to an anchor tag, which does not seem to be working (I get an error of "spellcheck.checkone is not a function".  I am trying to track down the reason why, and the more I dig, the harder it gets to trace.

Comment: @wblakenc Just do an alert/log of `spellcheck` and `spellcheck.checkone` first, and/or make sure the JS file is even loading--I mean, obviously it's a function, so perhaps something else is going on.

Comment: you're getting spellcheck.checkone is not a function because you need to have a return from your spellcheck that maps to the internal functions. e.g. at the end of your example you should have return { checkone: checkone, jspspellcheck: jspspellcheck };

Comment: Dave, thanks for the input.  It looks like it is is a pretty widely accepted way of writing js code.  I will see if I can figure out what is going on and leave the code as is.

Comment: @jbabey It's an anonymous object, not a function. Calling spellcheck.checkone() works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/8c8Lu/